# How do I hold hexidecimal letter values in an int? [C]

Tags: c, file-io, char, integer

I am writing a cache lab in C and I have got the whole input file to print in a char array, but any and all help for my cache lab online uses int to hold the input file, so I am thinking I need that too.
I have a three input files. One holds:

```
10
20
22
18
E10
210
12
```

I can get 10, 20, 22, 18 to print:

```
FILE* file;
int address;

file = fopen("address01" , "r");
while (fscanf(file, "%d", &address)) {
    printf("%d\n", address);
}
fclose(file);
```

but it stops after 18 since the next input is a char. I know characters can be held as an int on their own, so how can I also do this with the E and the 10 being together?

Comment: Read each line with `fgets` and process the string. If it begins with a non-digit character, do what is needed: not defined - ignore the line, ignore the first character...?

Comment: What are you expecting `address` to be when the input is `E10`?

Comment: If these are hex numbers, then use `%x` in both `scanf()` and `printf()`.

Comment: Integers are *not* "stored in a base".  Internally, integers are *integers*.  (Deep down they're binary, of course.)  But you don't "store an 'E'" in an integer.  If you take the three-character *string* `"110"` and convert it to `int` using `atoi`, `strtol` with a base of 10, or `scanf("%d")`, you will get the integer 110.  If you take the two-character string `"6E"` and convert it to `int` using`strtol` with a base of 16 or `scanf("%x")`, you will also get the integer 110.

Comment: Beware that `fscanf` is not line-based.  Repeatedly calling `fscanf("%x")` will work to read that input file just fine — but it will also perfectly happily read multiple whitespace-separated numbers off of one line, and it will also perfectly happily quietly skip blank lines, which may be what you want — or not.

Comment: Also, please change your `while` loop to `while(fscanf(…) == 1)`, as in the answer your accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%x` format specifier to read hexadecimal values into an `int`. For example:

```c
int address;

if (fscanf(file, "%x", &address) == 1) {
    printf("%d\n", address);
}
```

This will read the hexadecimal value `E10` into the `int` variable `address`.